# Gurobi-style model construction for Scipy.linprog?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, solver, gurobi

I want to compare Gurobi and Scipy's linear programming tools, such as linprog. Scipy requires to specify problems in a [matrix-list-vector-form](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) while Gurobi works like [here](http://examples.gurobi.com/traveling-salesman-problem/) such that

```
m = Model()
m.addVar(...) %for variables
m.addConstr(..>) %for constraints
m.update() %for updating the model
m.optimize % for optimizing the model
m.params %for getting parameters
m._vars %for getting variables
```

in comparison [`Scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

```
Minimize: c^T * x

Subject to: A_ub * x <= b_ub
A_eq * x == b_eq


c : array_like
Coefficients of the linear objective function to be minimized.
A_ub : array_like, optional
2-D array which, when matrix-multiplied by x, gives the values of the upper-bound inequality constraints at x.
b_ub : array_like, optional
1-D array of values representing the upper-bound of each inequality constraint (row) in A_ub.
A_eq : array_like, optional
2-D array which, when matrix-multiplied by x, gives the values of the equality constraints at x.
b_eq : array_like, optional
1-D array of values representing the RHS of each equality constraint (row) in A_eq.
bounds : sequence, optional
```

My goal is to write the code in only one method and still benchmark the results with both solvers. In order to speed up comparing the solvers:

1. Does there exist Gurobi-style model construction of LP problems for Scipy?
2. Does there exist some package to make the two methods interchangeable (I could write scipy-style for Gurobi or in Gurobi-style for Scipy)?
3. Does scipy provide any other interface to specify linear programming problems?

Comment: Hvae you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767608/sparse-matrix-lp-problems-in-gurobi-python) answer?

Comment: loannis: thank you but it is about sparse matrices that is not really relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a lot of work to show the obvious:

- Commercial solvers like Gurobi are much faster and much more robust than non-commercial ones

  - There are also high-quality benchmarks showing this by [H. Mittelmann](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html) (CLP and GLPK beeing the most popular non-commercial ones)
- While scipy's linprog is ok, it's much worse than the open-source competition including CBC/CLP, GLPK, lpSolve...

  - Speed and robustness!
  - Also: scipy's linprog really seems unmaintained [open issues](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20linprog)

There are some ways you could do that:

- **A)** Use linprog's way of problem-definition and convert this to Gurobi-style

  - very easy to convert-matrix form to Gurobi's modelling
- **B)** Use [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) as modelling-tool, [grab the standard-form](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/advanced/index.html#getting-the-standard-form) and write a wrapper for Gurobi (actually: there is one) and linprog (again easy). This would allow a very powerful modelling-language to be used by both

  - Disadvantage: Intransparent transformations according to the problem (e.g. `abs(some_vector)` might introduce auxiliary variables)
- **C)** Write some MPS-reader / or take one from other tools to model you problems within Gurobi, output these and read & solve within linprog

  - Candidate tools: [cvxopt's](http://cvxopt.org/) mps-reader (well-hidden in the docs), some GLPK-interface or even some CBC-interface
  - (Maybe hidden transformations)

No matter what you do, solution-process analysis will be a big part of your code as linprog might fail a lot. It's also not able to handle big sparse models.

**Remarks based on your gurobi-example**

- Your example (TSP) is a MIP, not an LP
- For MIP, everything said above get's worse (especially performance differences between commerical and open-source)
- There is no MIP-solver within scipy!

Comment: The op has no mention about TSP. Which formulation of TSP are you referring to with your remark `"Your example (TSP) is a MIP, not an LP"`?

Comment: Check your link ```Gurobi works like here```, which leads to some page ```The Traveling Salesman Problem
with integer programming and Gurobi```

Comment: CVXPY looks very nice, there is also Pulp. It looks like CVXPY is the top free product out there. Is that right? Specifying the problem is very similar to Gurobi which I like.

Comment: cvxpy is **very very different** from gurobi-like modelling. It's based on the idea of Disciplined Convex Programming,which is basically: proving convexity by construction. This also means: you can't express non-convex problems and maybe even some convex ones. Also: it likes matrix-like expressions and will be slow on others (which is different for gurobi). But you get a lof of powerful functions for free (much easier to formulate than within gurobi)

Comment: Hi, I see now there is a milp optimizer in scipy now, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a quite straight-forward manner.  It is not a lot of work like the prior post implied.
e.g.

```
res = linprog(c, A_ub=Aineq, b_ub=Bineq, A_eq=None if len(Aeq) == 0 else Aeq, b_eq=None if len(Beq) == 0 else Beq, bounds=x_bounds, method="highs", integrality=1)
if not res is None: return np.rint(res.x).astype(np.int64)
```

Translates to:

```
m = Model()
v = m.addVars(range(len(c)), lb=[x[0] for x in x_bounds], ub=[x[1] for x in x_bounds], vtype=[GRB.BINARY if x == (0,1) else GRB.INTEGER for x in x_bounds], name=labels)
m.addConstrs((sum(v[i]*a for i, a in enumerate(Aineq[j])) <= Bineq[j] for j in range(len(Aineq))))
m.addConstrs((sum(v[i]*a for i, a in enumerate(Aeq[j])) == Beq[j] for j in range(len(Aeq))))
m.setObjective(sum(v[i]*c[i] for i in range(len(c))), GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.update()
m.optimize()
return [int(v.x) for v in m.getVars()] if m.Status == GRB.OPTIMAL else None
```

Of course if not all your bounds are integer or binary, you might require more variable type handling, or other various possibilities scipy offers such as lists vs scalars, None values, etc.  Needless to say it can be done in a few lines of Python code.